# Does the Radeon R5450 have triple monitor support for Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, multiple-monitors

Not too long ago I went ahead and finally made the jump to Ubuntu, which lead me to spend several hours on google trying to find why my previous video card wasn't working, but with only one monitor. I came to find out it was blacklisted, so a couple hours later I finally decided to get a Radeon R5450 based on user recommendations for my standard dual screen setup.

However I noticed the card has 3 ports. VGA, DVI, and HDMI. So I said bump it let me try out 3 monitors I've been wanting to scale for a bit. So the monitors on the DVI and VGA work as expected, the one on the HDMI however not so much, I swapped the monitors around they all work its not just that monitor, just seems the port isn't putting anything out.

I've seen posts where people claim they have the same card as mine and use a triple head setup, so I am wondering how they pulled it off as they don't specify that part.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 currently. and a ATI Radeon R5450 card. Any ideas? Im at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this card has three outputs it can only do one digital and one analog output for a combination of 2 total. So you will not be able to run the both the HDMI and DVI at the same time as they are both Digital. If you look at the [ATI](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/Pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx) site you will see nothing about triple monitors mentioned however if you go up the model list you will see that cards that support 3 monitors have it mentioned in the product description.

Comment: doh! Well guess Ill just have to hold off on making the jump to 3 monitors, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the accepted answer, yes, the 5450 does provide triple monitor support *IF* it has a displayport connection. I have successfully gotten three monitors working in Ubuntu with a VisionTek 5450 with a displayport connection.

This particular card has DVI, VGA, and DisplayPort. There may be issues with 2XDVI + DisplayPort cards; I am not sure.

In my particular case I can confirm that DVI->VGA, DisplayPort->DVI, VGA->VGA works in Ubuntu with no headaches, for anyone who wants a cheap card that will get them triple monitors in linux.

Also, for anyone who tries it, DVI->VGA, DisplayPort->HDMI, VGA->VGA did not work. I could only get two monitors working at the same time.